# switching page and print properties bombs within ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-workflow-manager

within jobs launched from workflow manager, I am having a recurring bomb glitch when my users try and change their printer settings, or switch between printers/plotters.

Print drivers are updated.  Doesn't seem to matter on a specific printer/plotter.

Base maps settings pointing at a particular printer will hold, but if they go to change them, often ArcMap will bomb.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had this specific problem but have had ArcMap hang at the Print/Page settings dialog. One thing that sometimes helped was to change the default printer on the PC to a different printer. Also, I'm on Arc 10.4 now and the problem doesn't seem to occur anymore, so maybe upgrade to 10.4 on one of your machines if possible, to see if that solves the problem.